# How to add translation in opencart admin section depending on user?

Tags: php, opencart, shopping-cart

I'm using opencart version 1.5.5.1. We've a website coded using opencart framework. The site uses opencart multi-store feature also. I've added translation for language labels according to store as given in [How to use separate language files for opencart multi stores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161348/how-to-use-separate-language-files-for-opencart-multi-stores/).

Now the question is, is it possible to use different language labels in admin side for different users depending upon the store from which they created their user accounts. For example: One user creates an user account from the store related to sports items and another user creates an user account from the store related to wrist watches. So when the "sports" users login (admin side) we need to show language labels related to sports items and when the "wrist watches" users login (admin side) we need to show language labels related to watches.

Note: The new users are not super admins.

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here the problem is a little bit more complicated - You would have to catch the site the user registers at.

Open up Your phpMyAdmin (or Your desired DB administration tool) and edit the `customer` table by adding a new column, e.g. `register_site` of type e.g. `VARCHAR(20)`. You would save the site the registers at to this new column.

This means adding a `<input type="hidden" name="register_site" value="sports" />` or `<input type="hidden" name="register_site" value="watches" />` to the templates the stores are using, respectively. You would be editing two template files:

- `/catalog/view/theme/<THEME>/template/account/register.tpl`
- `/catalog/view/theme/<THEME>/template/checkout/register.tpl`

where You add the mentiond **hidden inputs** (only one adequote per store, switch `<THEME>` for the real themes name) and this model file:

- `/catalog/model/account/customer.php`

where You would have to edit the **`addCustomer`** method by adding a new coulmn-value pair to the `insert` SQL (should be line 14):

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "', firstname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['firstname']) . "', lastname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['lastname']) . "', email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "', telephone = '" . $this->db->escape($data['telephone']) . "', fax = '" . $this->db->escape($data['fax']) . "', salt = '" . $this->db->escape($salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9)) . "', password = '" . $this->db->escape(sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($data['password'])))) . "', newsletter = '" . (isset($data['newsletter']) ? (int)$data['newsletter'] : 0) . "', customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "', ip = '" . $this->db->escape($this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "', status = '1', approved = '" . (int)!$customer_group_info['approval'] . "', date_added = NOW(), register_site = '" . $this->db->escape($data['register_site']) . "'");
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --------- THIS IS NEWLY ADDED ---------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(Check the end of the line...).

Now in admin You could check the new `register_site` property/index in the logged in customer array and make the site behave accordingly (this should be straightforward now...).

Comment: Just to add to Shadyyx's answer. After you accomplish said above, look at line 124 in admin/index.php.This is where config language is set for the whole admin i believe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have the users storeids with me. Is there any way by default in opencart to provide translation in admin section?

Comment: At present the solution with me is to define a constant in header controller. Depending on the users storeid - change value of that constant and use it in language files for "SPORTS" and "WATCHES"! But I prefer a solution like: [How to use separate language files for opencart multi stores?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161348/how-to-use-separate-language-files-for-opencart-multi-stores/)

Comment: @SankarV So where's the problem then? Edit the controller file and add the code that will satisfy Your needs :-) Or update the question with the code causing You a problem (or better explain the problem coz I'm not quite sure what do You want from me right now...).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. In frontend we can use the language given for the store. Is there any such option available for setting admin language in such a way that I can create and make use of the language sections like: English_sports, English_watches etc.

Comment: @SankarV Then You have to edit the `/admin/index.php` file, not the header controller. You should be able to achieve this the very same way as within frontend. Let me know should You have any problems with this.

Comment: @SankarV: you select admin language in Admin System>Settings>[store] Local tab "Administration Language" option. Once you add a language to your opencart, you add it to both admin and front end. that's what is confusing you.